# Positioning images ontop each other in CSS and HTML

Tags: css, position, absolute

Have been trying to fix this problem I have here. Basically I have a website that has a background. Ontop of this background I have an centered image, lets call this image1. Exactly on top of image1 i want to draw image2. So basically I have a background which I want to draw two centered images ontop. I call them centeredImage and overlayImage.

Thank you for the help!
Best regards, Lukas

here is my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media=screen>

body{
    background-color:#f1e6d0;
    background-image:url('backgroundPattern.jpg');
}  
.containerPage
{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    width:1024;
    height:1515;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;      
}
.overlayImage1
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.overlayImage2
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

 </style>

 <title>A dream within a dream</title>
 </head>
 <body>


<!-- PAGE BEGINS -->
<div class= "containerPage">

    <!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
    <img class="overlayImage1" src="column.gif"  unselectable="on" height="1515" width="1024"/>
    <img class="overlayImage2" src="webSite_split_page1.gif" height="1515" width="1024"/>
    <!-- CONTENT BEGINS -->
    <!-- LEFT SIDE -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are after now. Try this. You will need to tweak the `top` value to get the correct vertical alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/frV3D/

```
body{
    background-color:#f1e6d0;
    background-image:url('backgroundPattern.jpg');
}  
.containerPage
{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    width:1024;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}

.centeredImage { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

.overlayImage {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-top: -150px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -150px; /* Half the width */
}
```

Comment: Btw, Anyone have a nice explanation of why the 50% are used in the overlayimage? Whats the logic behind that?

Comment: That centers the left edge of the image. You then use a negative margin equal to half its width to complete the centering

Answer (score 1):

Give a position value to anything you want to provide a z-index to - in this case your .centeredImage.

Comment: What kinakuta is saying in as few words as possible is that z-index only works on elements that have fixed, absolute or relative positioning. As centeredimage has none of these the z-index property does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the response! In the code I posted above the centeredImage is centered on the page. The problem is with the overlayImage because it is fixed to the left for some reason. I have tried to add position:relative to the centeredImage and it is still centered while overlayImage is not, if i add position:absolute it is also stuck to the left just as overlayImage. I cannot really wrap my head around this. For me the logical thing would be to define the area within the containerPage div and then all elements that follow has that as a reference....

Comment: It's fixed to the left because it has absolute positioning. How I would approach it is make both images child elements of a div that you give relative positioning. Center that div, then give the images absolute positioning and the appropriate z-indices.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have edited my code so it reflects your suggestion (I hope) still I cant really understand why they dont get centered by "containerPage". Now they are behaving like they should just that overlayImage1 & 2 are both aligned flush left and not centered. So the problem must be with my usage of centering in "containerPage". Anyone have any ideas?